# Ninjago set identification

Tags: set-identification, ninjago

I’m trying to identify a set to search for instructions. However all I know it is a Ninjago but cannot find the set on Google. It looks like a helicopter with out the blades on top. I am hoping someone might know what this is.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The pieces you have are from [Ronin R.E.X. (70735) set](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=70735-1).

[image]

Instructions can be downloaded from [LEGO Customer Service webpage](https://www.lego.com/en-us/service/buildinginstructions/70735).

Comment: Thank you Alex!!!